# Does lane choice matter?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In other MOBAs I play (mostly DOTA) lane choice can make or break certain heroes. And specific hero combos and soloing with the right hero are important for the overall game. Some heroes do better in mid, while others do better in long or short lanes. But in HotS, it seems that all heroes level up as a team. Also, the lanes seem to be about the same length in terms of distance between and meeting areas of creeps.

Other than not putting a squishy hero solo, and trying to pick decent combos for heroes laning together, does lane choice make any difference? Do any heroes do better or worse in any particular lanes?

Comment: The lanes don't matter so much, the only thing that matters is that there is atleast 1 person in every lane. You just need to be close to minions to share the exp. Other then that you are basically playing for the objectives anyway

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not as much as other MOBA's. While there is still a META forming in HotS, it's still not completely clear what kind of lanes are going to form game-to-game.

And because there are different maps, it adds a completely new complexity to the game that usually wasn't there before.

The general consensus from my experience playing the game is:

- Assassin + support
- Specialist + Warrior (then the specialist goes off and does something else mid game)
- Random solo lane

The random solo lane could be something like a fully offensive Tassadar who has good wave clear and goes for Archon ult. Another solo lane could be Zagarra with extra banes and focus on creep spread.

Lets focus on certain maps, though.

- Blackhearts Bay. You want 3 top and 2 bottom. This is because of the size of the map and you don't want to leave someone bottom by themselves. There is also a merc camp and a treasure chest down there so you have to prioritize it.
- Cursed Hollow. Generally a 2-1-2. That 1 in the middle lane will rotate for the curses.
- Dragon Shire. 2-1-2, but I've seen 1-2-2. Some games you want to go for control of the shrines, but I've seen games where teams have put 2 in the mid lane for dominance over the dragon shrine. It's almost impossible to take control of it when you are outnumbered, so teams sacrifice control over the shrines and roam a specialist.
- Haunted Mines. 2-2 with 1 roam. I constantly have 1 person roaming getting vision of enemies and trying to get jungle camps. Then I usually have 1 person staying out of the mines to create map pressure in other areas.
- Sky Temple and Garden of Terror. These are similar to Blackhearts Bay.

Comment: It may be important to note that heroes like Sgt. Hammer that have no mount often can be useless on maps like Cursed Hollow when they aren't mid, because they can't get to the tribute as quickly as others can. Going mid alleviates that problem for them.

Comment: @GarrettJ Yeah I think this answer is pretty good as it stands. I could go into every map and every hero, but that would basically be a million characters and writing an entire guide for HotS, so I decided to not get that specific and only provide a couple of examples of what I thought would describe the basic meta.

Comment: Any thoughts on Spider Queen's Tomb, now that the map is out?

Comment: @afsantos The Spider Queen's Tomb is VERY similar to Dragon Shire. It's usually a 2-1-2 but the laning phase ends very quickly - as soon as one team gets the 100 spider things.

Comment: As far as I know, going 4/1 on Haunted Mines is the common occurrence - did something change over the course of time or do you have arguments why you prefer 2-2 with 1 roamer over 4/1?

Comment: @r0estir0bbe The meta changes. If you notice this question was posted while the game was still in it's infancy. I answered it on March 16th. Like any MOBA, a lot of things can change, like team comps, new heroes and general strategy. My answer tries to cover a wide basis of the meta at the current time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna go with the answer **"No, lane choice doesn't really matter"**.

Lane choice for any hero depends heavily on the map, your team composition and enemy team composition. The most important part is as long as there are no objectives, there should be at least one person each lane to soak XP.

Then again, some heroes prefer to go together such as Uther-Hammer or in Blackheart's Bay, Tassadar/Valla/Nazeebo/Azmodan goes bottom lane. I have seen many pro teams go 4/1 on Haunted Mines. Also it is not wise to leave healer alone in a lane (given that there is **not** a combo like Nova-Zeratul is present in your team to roam together and leave 1 person each lane).

As long as you don't make the mistake of leaving a lane empty or not countering a heavy push enemies, you are good to go any lane.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, it matters a lot.

Depending on the map, there are lanes that you want to weaken faster than the others, or defend more than the others.

Also, the meta is more like a 1-4 team where the solo either roams two lanes and the four pressure another lane, or the solo keeps soaking a lane and the four are roaming around the map to gather XP

You also want to time your merc camps to apply pressure right before an objective pops out.

Let me give some examples

- Tomb of the spider queen's high priority lane is the top lane because of the boss, and then, it's bottom lane because of the giants - Here, you either want a 1 top 4 roam mid-bot, or a 4 roam top-mid 1 bot
- Cursed Hollow top priority lanes are top and bot because of boss and giants pressure, mid is just so-so - here, 1-1-1 and two roamers are fine, you just have to be able to get the your giant camp before the first objective pops if you want it so badly
- Warhead Junction's high priority lanes are top and bot as well, for the same reasons as Cursed Hollow... Once that lane is clear, boss pressure will be dangerous for the enemies, and those are the only lanes pushed by mercs
- For Dragon Shire, you want your solo to be top because it is quite dangerous to retreat on that straight line bridge before your keep entrance, you wouldn't want to lose more than a hero when getting ganked by surprise
- Garden Terror has no particular priority lane as each one can be equally pressured by mercs
- Blackheart's Bay, the best laning is a 1 top-mid and 4 bot as most of the fights will happen near Blackheart
- Sky Temple, bot lane
- Volskaya Foundry, top lane
- Towers of Doom, bot lane, then top, because of the sappers who can deal damage to the core
- Infernal Shrines, top lane
- On two lane maps, you just want to match the number of enemy heroes on each lane

This is just another way to see the macro game, maybe someday, these strats may change

Answer (score 1):

If you follow this link you'll find that using the drop down menu you can pull up any of the active Heroes with their talent suggestions based on what is being used by those that win.

http://www.heroesfire.com/hots/guide/hotslogs-hero-league-builds-with-highest-win-at-master-level-johanna-update-4341

Also, in the breakdown of the individual Heroes you will find that -some- are recommended for particular lanes or lane tactics.

So does lane selection matter? Yes and No.

If you're warming up in Vs AI or leveling a Hero (in AI) chances are you can go for broke with little risk.

As you move into "Quick Matches" or find yourself on a team you will want to try and communicate with your fellow players to decide on assignments. In Heroes of the Storm Objectives and Merc camps are extremely important so keeping the right Heroes in good positions to be able to control either of these as needed is very much a skill you will want to develop.

Fair warning unless it is a pre-made team communication is usually lacking in HotS but with experience you will be able to at-a-glance determine where you're likely to have the most success as some Heroes benefit from "laning" (as you will see if you read the various builds) with gains of Regen, Fresh Meat and other sorts of critical benefits to their play style/talents.

Answer (score 0):

> A lot of traditional MOBA mechanics are streamlined by Heroes of the
>   Storm. If players do a lot of cross lane business like map objectives,
>   they won’t “fall behind” due to teams leveling up and gaining
>   experience as a group.
>
> *Source: http://www.heroesofthestormsource.com/*

So, basically, no. Lane choice doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Lane choice matters.

Let me give example, in Blackheart's Bay the bottom lane fits specialist with pushing abilities the most. It's because they can push in this shortest lane. If you can win this lane, a lot of pressure will be given to enemy.

Also it depends on your team component too.
If you put weak hero in lane you will be suppressed easily.
On the contrary if you put strong combination lane like Jaina and Uther that lane will be stronger. Team composition is important.
More detail about team composition http://www.heroesofthestormbuildguide.com/guide/recommended-team-composition-in-hots/